Is InitCommonControlsEx() still needed when a manifest is present?
Is a call to InitCommonControlsEx() such as:
INITCOMMONCONTROLSEX icc;
icc.dwSize = sizeof(INITCOMMONCONTROLSEX);
icc.dwICC = ICC_STANDARD_CLASSES; // the right one?
InitCommonControlsEx(&icc);

needed in a presence of a following manifest:
#pragma comment(linker,"\"/manifestdependency:type='win32' \
name='Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls' version='6.0.0.0' \
processorArchitecture='*' publicKeyToken='6595b64144ccf1df' language='*'\"")

The Win32 application uses a dialog as a main form and does not explicitly create any windows inside the main function. The dialog currently holds only buttons. Without the call to InitCommonControlsEx, there are currently no compilation errors or warnings and the application seems to function without problems.

I think you need both. why not have both?

link to comctl32.dll via call/reference to InitCommonControls[Ex] load this dll to process. manifest from another side select version of comctl32.dll

It loads the DLL and registers the window classes.  The ones you need in the CreateWindowEx() or CreateDialog() call.  All that the manifest does is determine what version of the DLL you get, 6.0.0.0 has support for visual styles.  So yes, can't omit that call.

@HansPassant I do not have explicit calls to CreateWindowEx, only the CreateDialog in winMain.

Your dialog template does, eventually.

@HansPassant I see, thanks. How do I then decide on the content of the dwICC field?

It was useful back in the days that the OS had to run on a machine with 8MB of ram.  Those days are in the past, just ask for everything.

@user2470889189 you are supposed to specify the classes you actually use. It is your dialog, do you not know what controls are on it?

If InitCommonControls doesn’t do anything, why do you have to call it?

InitCommonControlsEx says An application must call this function before creating a common control.
